# cgroup v2: how to set `cpuset.cpus` for a slice in a unit file

Tags: cgroups

From `man systemd.resource_control`, it seems that there is no options for `cpuset` controller. Then how to set it in a unit file?

My purpose is to have the values set during boot time.

I know how to do it after booting by directly writing numbers into the corresponding `cpuset.cpus` file. But I'd like to have a way to persist the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man systemd.resource-control` points to: "AllowedCPUs="

Comment: Is this dependent on a particular version of systemd? The man pages on one system here (v219) don't have that AllowedCPUs option.

Comment: A quick search lands at https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/31d3a520297980ac31186e27396a05f928fde49f#diff-e846fc8ed54d1fd65293317afb5fa8acfdabe4b59629e8810e98b8c21bc40eae, indicating that Sept 15 2021 had a relevant commit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @yarl. How are the names like `AllowedCPUs` mapped to `cpuset.cpus` in the source code? If I want to set other `cpuset` interface, how can I get the correct key name in the unit file?

Comment: I found something like `cpuset_cpus` in the source code, but no `cpuset_cpus_partition`